# Updating monthly data, required to insert a new row if data does not exist

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

For the above table in excel (please refer to the picture), I am building a Macro to automatically update the monthly balance. I have the data from January to December, for simplicity, I assume there are only Jan and Feb data.

By using `VLOOKUP`, I am able to append the Feb balance to the adjacent column of Jan Balance. However, what concerns me is the new account of existing client every month(e.g. Client B 2345675555 in `Cell F8`), because `VLOOKUP` will simply ignore it. I need to copy the data of new Client ID and paste them into a new row under the existing table. Please note that the number of accounts for each client will only increase. Really appreciate if you could provide me with a solution (achievable with VBA Macro) .

Comment: Sorry, I know this doesn't help with the problem at hand, but this data structure looks really cancerous, and I assume this data will be summarized somewhere else for viewing. Is it possible to gather this data to a single table, with a column for month?

Comment: @mpn275 Thanks for your reply. In the real case, each month balance is stored at different sheets within the SAME workbook. For example, January's data in Worksheets("Jan"). And I also have a master sheet to get the final result.

Comment: OK, looks like you got an answer already, but if possible, you should look if you can collect all data on a single sheet in a table with columns 'Id', 'Name', 'Month', 'Amount', where Amount will be the change in balance (i.e the sum of all events in that month). Then a running total gives the balance for any month. As a general principle, the better the data structure, the less macros you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagined your "Jan" sheet, in fact, to be your "Master" sheet which would have all the months names in its header row, and these would also be the names of the worksheets in the same workbook from which you want to import the balances.

In consequence, I arrived at the idea that you could just double-click a month name on the "Master" sheet (name doesn't matter) and import the balances from the sheet whose name you clicked (name must match exactly) into the column that you clicked. The code below does exactly that. Like in VLOOKUP, the sequence in which that sheet lists the client names is immaterial. But new names will be added at the bottom. Before the next run you can sort them differently. Unlike when you use VLOOKUP, there is no permanent link between the sheets. Here's the code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, _
                                        Cancel As Boolean)
    ' 084
    
    Const TriggerRow    As Long = 1         ' change to suit
    
    Dim TabName         As String           ' worksheet name to update from
    Dim WsS             As Worksheet        ' data source: Tabname
    
    With Target
        If .Row = TriggerRow Then           ' skip if row is different
            TabName = .Value
            If Len(TabName) Then            ' if the clicked cell isn't blank
                On Error Resume Next
                Set WsS = Worksheets(TabName)
                If Err Then
                    MsgBox "The worksheet """ & TabName & """ hasn't been set up yet.", _
                           vbInformation, "Invalid tab name"
                Else
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = False      ' this is faster
                    TransferBalances Target, WsS
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                End If
            End If
            Err.Clear
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub TransferBalances(Target As Range, _
                             WsS As Worksheet)
    ' 084
    
    ' the same columns are used in both the Master and all Source sheets
    ' columns need not be positioned in numeric sequence (1 = "A", 2="B" etc)
    Const NameClm   As Long = 1         ' specify the column where the Client names are
    Const IdClm     As Long = 2         ' specify the column where the Client IDs are
    Const BalClm    As Long = 3         ' specify the column where the balance are
    
    Dim IdRng       As Range            ' existing IDs in "Master" sheet
    Dim SrcRng      As Range            ' cell range containing source data
    Dim Src         As Variant          ' value of SrcRng (for faster access)
    Dim R           As Long             ' loop counter: Rows
    Dim Rt          As Long             ' target row
    
    With Target.Worksheet
        Set IdRng = .Range(.Cells(1, IdClm), .Cells(.Rows.Count, IdClm).End(xlUp))
        ' the range will not be extended to include added items
    End With
    
    With WsS
        R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, IdClm).End(xlUp).Row        ' last used row (IdClm)
        ' row 2 is the first row with data to be transferred
        ' copy all columns from A to the last one used in row 1
        Set SrcRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), _
                            .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(R - 1))
    End With
    Src = SrcRng.Value
    
    For R = 1 To UBound(Src)
        On Error Resume Next
        Rt = WorksheetFunction.Match(Src(R, IdClm), IdRng, 0)
        With Target.Worksheet
            If Err Or (Rt = 1) Then             ' disallow match in header row
                Rt = .Cells(.Rows.Count, IdClm).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Rows(Rt - 1).Copy
                .Rows(Rt).Insert Shift:=xlDown  ' copy formats from above
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                .Cells(Rt, NameClm).Value = Src(R, NameClm)
                .Cells(Rt, IdClm).Value = Src(R, IdClm)
            End If
            .Cells(Rt, Target.Column).Value = Src(R, BalClm)
        End With
    Next R
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Since the code responds to the double-click event it must be installed in your Master worksheet's code module. This location is essential because the double-click won't be noticed anywhere else in your workbook. Only by pasting the code in that module can you enjoy the promised automation.

Comment: Glad you like it @czxc. However, heroes get their answers marked "Selected" :-)